# cytoscape.js graph, shows/draws only with few nodes and edges

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am creating a graph with Cytoscape.js on my website, to show admins the connections among users. Everything is fine, but some graph are not drawn down. No errors in console, but the canvas seems empty.

For example, a graph that is not drawn has 20 EDGES and 18 NODES.
If I remove some edges, the graph is drawn and showed. No matter to which node or edge I remove: if I reach 18 EDGES it shows. So I thought "maybe it's too large".

But actually I have bigger graphs (37 edges) that are drawn without problems.

What can be the problem?

This is a graph that it's **not** showing.  By the way, is there an online website where I can test this structure? Thanks

```
{
    "elements": {
        "nodes": [
            {"data": {"id": "1"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "2"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "3"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "4"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "5"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "6"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "7"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "8"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "9"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "10"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "11"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "12"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "13"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "14"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "18"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "15"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "16"}}, 
            {"data": {"id": "17"}}
            ],
        "edges": [{
            "data": {
                "source": "1",
                "target": "2"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "1",
                "target": "3"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "4",
                "target": "3"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "5",
                "target": "3"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "1",
                "target": "6"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "7",
                "target": "6"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "1",
                "target": "8"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "9",
                "target": "1"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "1",
                "target": "9"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "1",
                "target": "10"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "4",
                "target": "10"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "1",
                "target": "11"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "1",
                "target": "4"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "8",
                "target": "12"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "14",
                "target": "13"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "8",
                "target": "13"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "15",
                "target": "18"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "11",
                "target": "18"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "11",
                "target": "16"
            }
        }, {
            "data": {
                "source": "17",
                "target": "16"
            }
        }],
    },
}
```

Comment: What layout are you using? I tried it with dagre and grid and the nodes are showing up as they should?

Comment: ` layout: {name: 'breadthfirst', directed: true, padding: 15}`

Comment: What do you mean by online site to test "this structure"?

Answer (score 2):

I got the elements to display just fine:

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'height': '60px',
        'width': '60px',
        'border-color': 'black',
        'border-opacity': '1',
        'border-width': '10px'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: '$node > node',
      css: {
        'padding-top': '10px',
        'padding-left': '10px',
        'padding-bottom': '10px',
        'padding-right': '10px',
        'text-valign': 'top',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'background-color': '#bbb'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ':selected',
      css: {
        'background-color': 'black',
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'source-arrow-color': 'black'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "7"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "11"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "12"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "14"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "15"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "16"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "17"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "18"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "1",
          target: "2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "1",
          target: "3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "4",
          target: "3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "5",
          target: "3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "1",
          target: "6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "7",
          target: "6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "1",
          target: "8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "9",
          target: "1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "1",
          target: "9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "1",
          target: "10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "4",
          target: "10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "1",
          target: "11"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "1",
          target: "4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "8",
          target: "12"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "14",
          target: "13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "8",
          target: "13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "15",
          target: "18"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "11",
          target: "18"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "11",
          target: "16"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "17",
          target: "16"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'breadthfirst',
    directed: true,
    padding: 15
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I figured out that without `directed:true` works also to me. Anyway, yours work also with that property. ummh...

Comment: You could post a minimal version of your code (html, css and js), that way we could find out what went wrong exactly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

In my case, the height of the `cy`'s div was equal to zero, meaning I see nothing.

I fixed it using this css styles:

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    #cy {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90%;
    }
```

The crucial point is to make sure the `html` and the `body` fill the entire page, thus `div#cy` will occupy 90% of that screen space, and the graph will be there using any layout we use.